# A better function to perform multiple replaces in a text, specified by arrays?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 text arrays, the first contains the string set that I am looking for, and the second is the string that I need to be replaced when found. PostgreSQL offers the string function `replace(text,text,text)`....

Is there a simple implentation or library that offers an optimized version of `replace(text,text[],text[])` function? 
PS: or similar thing.

---

### NOTES

- [this question about character-replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19957048/287948) is similar bot not a duplicate.
- answering the "use case" that @Bergi asked: the replace is the main piece in any user-defined *template system engine* (imagine for example an pure-SQL [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) implementation). 
  Imagine that you need massive "on the fly" (real time) *string replaces* to use it in an REST API like [PostgREST](http://postgrest.org/) or [PostGraphile](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/).
- I need optimized version (in C or something with better performance) of the "not optimized example" below.

```sql
-- not optimized implentation:
CREATE FUNCTION agg_replace_fn(
  oldtxt text, txt text, fnd text, rpl text
) RETURNS text AS $f$
  SELECT CASE
   WHEN oldtxt>'' AND txt>'' AND fnd>'' THEN replace( oldtxt, fnd, rpl )
   WHEN (oldtxt IS NULL OR oldtxt='') AND txt>'' AND fnd>'' THEN replace( txt, fnd, rpl )
   ELSE COALESCE(txt,'')
   END
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
CREATE AGGREGATE agg_replace(text,text,text) (
  sfunc = agg_replace_fn,
  stype = text,
  initcond = ''
);

CREATE FUNCTION replace(txt text, fnd text[], rpl text[]) RETURNS text AS $f$
  SELECT agg_replace(txt,f,r) 
  FROM unnest(fnd) WITH ORDINALITY t1(f,idx) 
       NATURAL JOIN  unnest(rpl) WITH ORDINALITY t2(r,idx)
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
-- to test: 
SELECT 
  replace('axbcde abxcdefg etc', array['ax','bx','e'], array['a!','b0','@'])
  = 
  'a!bcd@ ab0cd@fg @tc'
;
```

As @Bergi suggested, showing the performance problem:

```sql
-- Benchmark:
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT 
  replace('axbcde abxcdefg etc', array['ax','bx','e'], array['a!',i::text,'@'])
FROM generate_series(1,10000) t(i); -- 3 replaces per row, total 30000
--  Execution Time: 804.722 ms

EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT 
  replace('axbcde abxcdefg etc', i::text, 'b0')
FROM generate_series(1,10000*3) t(i); -- one replace per row, total 30000
-- Execution Time: 12.616 ms
```

So the "optimized" is ~60 times faster.

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling the function, the use case where it is too slow?

Comment: In Postgraphile I'd recommend to do the templating in the node.js API server, not in pure SQL. But interesting question nonetheless!